# Which archive did an installed package come from?

Tags: package, package-repositories

When I use `list-packages` it shows the archive for packages that are not installed, but not for ones that are. The same for package descriptions. Is there any way to find out which archive an installed package came from?

(Yes, I can search each archive I use, but I was hoping for something quicker & easier.)

Answer (score 1):

Emacs only stores which packages you selected for installation, AFAIK.

With 2 steps you can sort the package list to guess where you installed from:

After `list-packages` use "`(`" package-menu-toggle-hiding, position you point in column 3 where the package names begin and hit `S` for tabulated-list-sort to sort by package names.

The installed and available versions are now displayed right next to each other and should give a hint where the package was installed from.

Comment: Thanks, that helps for some packages. For most of them, though, it only shows the one version, with no info about which archive it's from. It would be nice if the package system remembered the archive when it installed a packge. Oh, well.